# PowerShell Get-ChildItem search in the directory Above

Tags: powershell

I want to search for a file in the parent directory. So far I have

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.xap
```

What I want is to search for this file in the parent directory (the file is located in another folder in the parent folder). Any advice on how to do this with PowerShell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the `Path` parameter with a value of `..`, so use the parent directory as the base of your search:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path .. -Filter *.xap
```

If the file(s) you're looking for are not located directly inside the parent directory, but another subdirectory of the parent, either use the `-Recurse` switch parameter to perform a recursive search, or use `..` in a relative path:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path ..\otherfolder
```

or

```
Get-ChildItem -Path .. -Recurse
```